# How do you pronounce the soft reish?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters

From the Sefer Yetzirah it seems that there is both a hard and soft letter reish ([see 4th perek, Aryeh Kaplan edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=18fLFow9QKgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=they%20direct%20themselves%20with%20two%20tounges&f=false)). How do you pronounce the soft reish?

Comment: I've never opened _Sefer Y'tzira_, but note that there are seventeen _reshin d'gushos_ in _Tanach_. I haven't checked any of them to determine whether it has a dagesh lene or a dagesh forte.

Comment: @msh210 IIRC They all seem like degeshim fortiim.

Comment: @msh210 kaplan lists 14 used in 10 discrete words, my question is how exactly are those letters properly pronounced. ps. you should totally open a sefer y'tzira, it's awesome.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave I don't seem to have a hard copy handy, so it would be nice if either you can link to it or magically form me one.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave: seventeen are (list stolen from elsewhere, and I haven't even checked for accuracy): I Sam 1.6, 10.24, 17.25; II Reg 6.32; Jer 39.12; Ezek 16.4, 16.4; Hab 3.13; Job 39.9; Ps 52.5; Prov 3.8, 11.21, 14.10, 15.1; Cant 5.2; Ezra 9.6; II Chr 26.10.

Comment: @DoubleAA poof! http://books.google.com/books?id=18fLFow9QKgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=they%20direct%20themselves%20with%20two%20tounges&f=false

basic text - http://www.hermetics.org/pdf/Sefer_Yetzirah_Kaplan.pdf

Comment: I should be _mevi g'ula laolam_ and say where I got my list from. It's from two November 2008 posts on AishDas's `mesorah` listserv.

Comment: Why are you asking for the soft reish? What we have sounds more like a soft reish as it is not plosive. Maybe you should ask about the hard reish.

Comment: @DoubleAA not being a linguist i'm taking kaplan's word that the hard one is what we currently use, not the soft one.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave - Almost all instances of the *reish* are supposed to be soft. R' Kaplan actually says that he thinks the fricative *reish* that is used (at least by Israelis) is appropriate for the soft *reish*. As per DoubleAA, R' Kaplan stated that the hard *reish* is unknown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Hebrew dialect of Habbani Jews (type of Temanim), we maintain a double pronunciation of resh, as well as a few other sounds I'm not aware of other dialects having.

The main pronunciation of resh is a regular rolled r, like exists in Arabic and Spanish.
**The soft resh is much like an English r, but more emphatic, as if you were about to roll it but stopped short.** You can still hear this sound in some old Arabic music. The fact that this sound existed in earlier Arabic I'm sure is along the lines of more than 50% of root words in Arabic come from Hebrew - not the other way around.

Interestingly, in Habbanit our hard gimel is neither j nor g, but a kind of clicking g sound. (Soft gimel is "gh")
Samekh is best described as the s sound after the k in "Mexico" (since x is truly k-s), with the tongue positioned lower than in a regular s sound.
Quf is a guttural "g" sound, not as intense as the Iraqi version.
Everything else is the same as normative Temani dialect.

This stuff fascinates me. ^_^

Comment: Also, I think pronouncing Hebrew with the most authentic and original pronunciation is important for spiritual aspects as brought in Sefer Yetzira. Even if it means you think Iraqi or another Temani is more authentic than Habbanit (I won't be offended). But in actuality, Iraqi and Temani dialects are almost the exact same, only with minor differences. And I believe they are the root of the Ashkenazi dialect, where waw became vav, thaw became sav, etc (a double pronunciation of tav not being maintained by many Sepharadim).

Comment: +1, but if you could use IPA symbols it'd help a lot: personally (though I may be alone) I have no idea what you mean by "gh" or "clicking g", nor really what you mean by "much like an English r, but more emphatic, as if you were about to roll it but stopped short".

Comment: Can you clarify which Reish's get which pronunciation, as most Tanach texts do not seem to differentiate?

Comment: Make a normal g sound, move is SLIGHTLY forward towards your teeth, and emphasize it to the point that it clicks. Ethiopians, who speak Semitic languages, have this sound as well. "Gh" is "ghayin" in Arabic, as in "Baghdad", it sounds almost like the French r.
English r is as in American English, or West Country England English. Move your tongue forward more to emphasize the sound, and that is basically it.

Comment: @InSearchofEMeTh, there is very rarely a resh dgusha in the Tanakh, although I remember seeing one in Shir HaShirim. My Rav tells me his father knew when you would use it, and it was much more often, but I personally don't know. I wish I did.

Comment: @Aman; this stuff fascinates me, too. Where in Sefer Yetzirah does it mention the thing about pronouncing Hebrew in the (hopefully) most authentic way? And, tangentally, is it my imagination or does trying to pronounce words 'authentically' actually take more time to physically execute than pronouncing them in, say, Yeshivish Ashkenazi? (I always fall behind; I blame the sh'va nachs and dageshim chazakim!)

Comment: #1. Aman, that's unbelievable. #2. you should make a youtube video delineating the various pronunciations.

Comment: @Aman - I recall hearing that the only *reish* that should be emphasized is in 1 Shmuel 1:6.

Comment: @Shemmy I say that because the Hebrew letter has a correct number, sound, color, spiritual power, etc associated with it. Part of using the power of a letter in speech is dependant on pronouncing it correctly. No two Hebrew letters should sound the same. Only in Habbanit are they all different.
When I became religious and took this nusah, I had to learn all the letters we don't have in English, or in some other dialects of Hebrew.

Comment: @Fred That is highly unlikely. It's one of the few that make it into common public reading (and likely to be overlooked, certainly), but even there it isn't unique. Consider Habakuk 3:13. Ezra 9:6 shows up in many versions of Selichot and Shir HaShirim (including 5:2) is read in various contexts by various communities.

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't forget Psalms 52:5 and (for those who recite Job on Tisha B'Av) Job 39:9!!!

Comment: @msh210, I wonder if you could now translate Aman's description into IPA symbols?

Comment: @Aman, from your description I heard that all the consonants are unique. But wasn't clear to me: Do each of the doubled consonants have sounds that are the _same_ except that one form is softer than the other (i.e., fricative or such), like we all do kaf/chaf? Your description of gimel/ghimel didn't sound that way?

Answer (score 4):

Hidāyat al-Qāriʾ (see Eldar's edition) indicates that the regular resh pronunciation was articulated at the middle of the tongue. This is farther out than the articulation for fricative gimel (IPA: ʁ) or the fricative kaf (IPA: χ), which was articulated "at the back third of the tongue". This suggests that resh had an advanced uvular articulation. It is unclear if it is a roll (IPA: ʀ) or frictionless continuant (IPA: ʁ̖).

The second resh (called "heavy"), which is found in the environment of the alveolar consonants דזצתטסלן was probably an alveolar trill, like the one used for resh in Middle Eastern Hebrew. The terminology used to refer to this resh (makrūḵ) and other evidence suggests that this resh was emphatic.

Saʿadya Gaʿon writes in his commentary on Sefer Yeṣirah that Tiberians have a dual form of resh (hard and light), but the Babylonians do not.

See Khan's *A Short Introduction to the Tiberian Masoretic Bible and its Reading Tradition*.